# iOS XMPP client not connecting to openfire local server

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire

I have setup an openfire server on my local machine and created few users.
Now when I am trying to connect to this server from my iOS application but it is throwing below error in console

```
RECV: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
```

But when I try to connect using spark client app it is successfully connecting to the local openfire server.

I am using [robbiehanson/XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) as an iOS client

and passing userid as "user1@ServerName" where ServerName is "Server Name" value shown in openfire admin console.

Is there any thing more I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind you have to follow below way.

```
 user: username@rakeshs-Mac-mini.local
    groupname@conference.rakeshs-mac-mini.local
    at time of groups Create : write ->  conference.rakeshs-mac-mini.local
```

## warning Set here Server Name...like below in Appdelegate.m

if([domain isEqualToString:@"rakeshs-mac-mini.local"])
    {}

```
NSString *myJID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kXMPPmyJID];
NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kXMPPmyPassword];

if (myJID == nil || myPassword == nil) {
    return NO;
}
```

## warning Set Username as username@servername

```
myJID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@rakeshs-Mac-mini.local",myJID];

[xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];
password = myPassword;

NSLog(@"username: %@,Password : %@",myJID,myPassword);
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. Everything is in place but still same issue
I tried "user1@xxxxxx.people.local" , "user1@localhost" and "user1@xx.x.x.50"(local ip)

Comment: well what is "/xmppframework" appended to myJID in your example by the way?

Comment: i had remove it, it was unnecessory.

Comment: userid@servername or username@serverAddress..eg. 1@54.25.65.85

Comment: @PrafulKadam, try this like. 1@54.25.65.85

Comment: still no luck. I hope ssl and running both server and client on local is not an issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86856/discussion-between-mehul-and-praful-kadam).